# Stripe payment trigger All modals to open

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments

When i put credits and make a payment the payment is succesfull but for some reason after the payment stripe is triggering all modals to open(from header), like it setting true all the modals , anyone know why ?  ( The modal is from another compoenent name "Header" its working fine with everything else in my app .

Code below :

Merry Christmas :)

```
//React imports
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Pressable, Alert, Image , KeyboardAvoidingView , Dimensions , Platform} from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation , useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';
//Icon imports
import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons'; 
import { FontAwesome5 } from '@expo/vector-icons';
//API imports
import axios from 'axios';
import { StripeProvider, CardField, CardFieldInput, createToken, confirmPayment } from '@stripe/stripe-react-native';
import { Buffer } from "buffer";
//useConfirmPayment,useStripe
//My imports
import Header from './Header';
//.Env imports
import {URL} from '@env';

export default function Payment({route}) {

  //Constructors for Card Details
  const [card, setCard] = useState(CardFieldInput.Details | null);
  //Use of navigate Hook
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  //My local variables
  const bookItem = route.params.paramKey;
  const bookID = bookItem.id;
  const bookPrice = bookItem.Price;
  const bookImage = bookItem.image;

  //Payment function
  const pay = async () => {
  
    //First we create token for the payment
    const resToken = await createToken({...card,type:'Card'})

    //Then we create data for the payment , like amount and currency
    const payData = {
      amount : bookPrice * 100,
      currency : "eur",
    }
    console.log(payData)
   //If credit card fields are correct fil out ,then continue to further confirmations
    if(Object.keys(resToken) == "token"){
    //Request to check the success of the payment 
    await axios.post(URL+"/createPayment", 
    {...payData}).then((response)=>{
      const { confirmPaymentIntent } = confirmPayment(response.data.paymentIntent,{paymentMethodType : 'Card'})
    
      //If confirm is true then update the book table in Bought Column
      if(Object.keys(response.data).length > 1){
        Alert.alert("Success payment")
        //Request to inform the table that this book is bought
        axios.post( URL+"/bookBuy",
        {
          bookCheckID : bookID,
          userBoughtItID : global.id
        }).catch((error)=>{
          console.log("Axios request failed to buy the book")
        })
        //End of second Axios request
      }
      else
      {
        console.log("Token Error ,maybe card credits is wrong")
        Alert.alert("Error in payment,maybe card credits are wrong?")
      }
    }).catch((error)=>{
      console.log("Axios request for payment failed")
    })
    //End of first Axios request
  }
  else{
    Alert.alert("Card credentials are not Valid")
  }
}


  



return (
    
  //Stripe public key provider
  <StripeProvider
    publishableKey = "pk_test_51MAWjfI5vsjFWvGhrr5n2mAujexURegEgW4ujlSPpois9Em7FBzHrEkuv5zkeRjck8CeLBAcI761eVqgWQ3mL6EX00oSp0WeB6"
     merchantIdentifier = "merchant.com.{{E-LIBRARY}}" 
     urlScheme = "your-url-scheme" 
  >

  <KeyboardAvoidingView
      style={{ height: Platform.OS ==='ios' ? Dimensions.get('window').height * 1 : Dimensions.get('window').height * 1}}
      behavior={(Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 'position' : "position"}
      enabled
      keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.select({ ios: -50, android: -50 })}
  
  >
  <View style = {styles.container}>
    
    {/* Header */}
    <Header />
 
    
      {/* Container */}
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style = {styles.viewContainerForInfos}>
          <Text style = {styles.bookText}>{bookItem.title}</Text>
          <View style = {styles.imageView}>
            <Image 
              style = {{width:'30%',height:'60%',borderRadius:22,position:'relative',resizeMode:'contain'}}
              source = {{uri :'data:image/png;base64,' + Buffer.from(bookImage.data,'hex').toString('base64')}}  
            />
            <AntDesign name="checkcircleo" size={24} color="white" style = {{}} />
          </View>
        </View>
        
        <View style = {styles.viewForCardinfo}>
          <Text style = {styles.creditText}>Credit Card Informations</Text>
          <FontAwesome5 name="id-card-alt" size={30} color="black" />
        </View>

        <View style = {{alignItems:'center',width:'100%',height:'100%'}}>

          {/* Card component from Stripe */}
          <CardField
            postalCodeEnabled={true}
            placeholder={{
              number: '4242 4242 4242 4242',
            }}
            cardStyle={{
              backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
              textColor: '#000000',
              borderWidth:2,
              borderRadius:15
            }}
            style={{
              width: '80%',
              height: '8%',
              marginVertical: '15%',
            }}
            onCardChange={(cardDetails) => {
              setCard(cardDetails);
            }}
          />

        {/* Pressable in order for the client to pay */}
        <Pressable style = {styles.pressable} onPress = {() => {pay()}}>
            <Text style = {styles.pressableText}>Buy</Text>
        </Pressable>

      </View>
        

      </View>

  </View>

  </KeyboardAvoidingView>

  </StripeProvider>

  )
  
}
```

Header

```
//React imports
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Pressable, Modal, Platform} from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
//Icon Imports
import { SimpleLineIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
//Icons inside header modal
import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons'; 
import { Feather } from '@expo/vector-icons'; 

export default function Header() {

  //Use of navigation Hook
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  //Modal Constructor
  const [modalVisible,setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  

    return (
    
    <View style = {styles.Container}>

   

      {/* Modal*/}
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
        }}>

        <View style = {styles.modalStyle}>
          
          {/* Pressable and Text for each functionality  */}
          <Pressable  style = {styles.pressable} onPress = { () => navigation.navigate('Home')}>
            <AntDesign name="home" size={24} color="black" style = {{marginRight:'2%',marginLeft:'2%'}}/>
            <Text style = {styles. textInsideModalPressables}>Home</Text>
          </Pressable>
            
          <Pressable  style = {styles.pressable} onPress = { () => navigation.navigate('MyBooks')}>
          <Feather name="book" size={24} color="black" style = {{marginRight:'2%',marginLeft:'2%'}}/>
            <Text style = {styles. textInsideModalPressables}>My Collection</Text>
          </Pressable>

          <Pressable  style = {styles.pressable} onPress = { () => navigation.navigate('Profile')}>
            <AntDesign name="profile" size={24} color="black" style = {{marginRight:'2%',marginLeft:'2%'}}/>
            <Text style = {styles. textInsideModalPressables}>Profile</Text>
          </Pressable>
          
          
          <Pressable style = {styles.pressable} onPress = { () => navigation.navigate('Settings')}>
            <Feather name="settings" size={24} color="black" style = {{marginRight:'2%',marginLeft:'2%'}}/>
            <Text style = {styles. textInsideModalPressables}>Settings</Text>
          </Pressable>  

          <Pressable style = {styles.pressable} onPress = { () => navigation.navigate('LogInPage')}>
            <AntDesign name="logout" size={24} color="black" style = {{marginRight:'2%',marginLeft:'2%'}}/>
            <Text style = {styles. textInsideModalPressables}>Log Out</Text>
          </Pressable> 

          <Pressable onPress={ () => {setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}} style = {styles.pressable}>
            <AntDesign name="closecircleo" size={24} color="black" style = {{marginRight:'2%',marginLeft:'2%'}}/>
            <Text style = {styles. textInsideModalPressables}>Close modal</Text>
          </Pressable>

        </View>


      </Modal>

      {/* Pressable Mechanism in order to open the Modal */}
      <Pressable onPress={ () => {setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}} style = {styles.pressableMenu}>
        <SimpleLineIcons style = {styles.iconMenu} name="menu" size={24} color="white" />
        <Text style = {styles.menuText}>Menu</Text>
      </Pressable>

      <View style ={{width:'50%',alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center'}}>
        <Text style = {styles.nameText}> E-Library</Text>
      </View>
   
    </View>
  );}
```

Comment: Is your goal to not display the Header component when the payment is successful? If so, create a new boolean variable `hasPaid`, and display `<Header />` only when that variable is false.

Comment: The Header component must be there all the time so the user can navigate to another screens to .But when i make the payment it opens for no reason.

Comment: If you always want the Header component visible, but you want to display it differently, then maybe add some props to it? Something like `<Header isOpen={true} />`, and change that prop to `false` when the user paid. Hard to say without more information.

Comment: OK i did some edits and put the header file,the thing is that  i need always to set true but the modal must be false until i press it .

Comment: Actually this does it only on Android devices..on ios works perfect. Strange..